# How to create a folder in Django to store user inputs

Tags: python-3.x, django, file, opencv, video-processing

Goal of Code:

1. User uploads a video to our django site.
2. Use opencv to split it up into individual frames (this works well).
3. We store the frames in a unique folder on our backend (this is where the problem lies).

What we need help with:

1. Creation of a unique folder based on user inputted video with django with correct path.
2. Save the frames of the video into that folder.

The code thus far:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
import uuid
import cv2
import os
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from django.urls import reverse
from PIL import Image


class Video(models.Model):
    vid = models.FileField(upload_to=image_upload_location(filename='jpg'))
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_location(filename='jpg'))
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def mp4_to_image(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is part we struggling with, creating a unique folder for each video input.
This code works on my local computer path however we need to integrate it with django framework

```
        try:
           if not os.exists('exit_folder_path'):
           os.makedirs('exit_folder_path')
        except OSError:
           print ('Error: Creating directory')
```

Here we use opencv to split the video into individual frames and then save them.

The imwrite() function saves the frame as a jpeg in path defined by name parameter.

We would like these files to be saved to the folder path defined in previous section.

```
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.vid.path)
        currentFrame = 0
        while (True):
        # ret returns a Boolean Value if the frame can be read
           ret, frame = cap.read()
           # If the frame can't be read then we exit the loop
           if ret == False:
              break
           # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
            
            name = 'exit_folder_path' + str(currentFrame).zfill(6) + '.jpg'
           
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
           
            currentFrame += 1

        cap.release()
```

Problems:

1. The code saves the user inputted video to a folder called jpg, but no folder is created with the individual frames from the video.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a media folder.
Check here -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/